# C# vs studio unassigned variable warning for variables assigned during code blocks

Tags: c#, visual-studio, variables

When you declare a variable but never use it, you get a squiggly line underneath that warns you. I like it a lot.

But what about if you assign those variables during an if or for statement but it still sees them as unassigned due to accessibility, is there a setting that actually allows this and doesn't warn or at least has a different squiggly line color setting?

Comment: Can you collaborate with an example? I cannot recall any circumstances where the behaviour you're mentioning is playing up.

Comment: Well, in an if block the variable would not be assigned on all code paths.

Comment: The problem with assigning inside an `if` or a `for` loop is that code may never get run so you cannot guarantee the variable has been assigned a value. The safest option there is to give it a default value on declaration. So instead of `int x;` use `int x = 0;`

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. I appreciate it.